# How do I loop 5 times to decide who will be the winner of the rock and paper scissors game?

Tags: javascript

I am planning to make a score. Whoever gets to 5 points of winning, wins the game.

So far, I have tried to use for loops to checkWinner() but it's not going as planned

After the winner has been decided, I would need to press play again to restart the whole game

```js
cardText.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  player = button.textContent;
  getComputerChoice();

  playerScore.textContent = `Player: ${player}`;
  computerScore.textContent = `Computer: ${computer}`;
  resultText.textContent = checkWinner();
}));

function getComputerChoice() {
  const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  switch (randNum) {
    case 1:
      computer = "Rock";
      break;
    case 2:
      computer = "Paper";
      break;
    case 3:
      computer = "Scissors";
      break;
  }
}

function checkWinner() {
  if (player == computer) {
    return "Draw";
  } else if (computer == "Rock") {
    return (player == "Paper") ? "You Win !" : "You Lose"
  } else if (computer == "Paper") {
    return (player == "Scissors") ? "You Win !" : "You Lose"
  } else if (computer == "Scissors") {
    return (player == "Rock") ? "You Win !" : "You Lose"
  }
}
```

Comment: is it your lab at school? :))

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for